# Читабельность пакетов

Tags: oracle, package

Сейчас пытаюсь в оракле создавать пакеты. Выделил группу процедур и функций и ставил в один пакет. А потом задумался. Раньше у меня все процедуры были отдельными вкладками. А теперь я получил один пакет на десяток экранов и читабельность всего кода резко упала.

Вопрос, это издержки моей IDE (EMS Oracle Studio), которая показывает все процедуры сплошным текстом, или так работают все IDE? Если все, то есть ли методы повышения читабельности пакета? Вставлять какие-то видимые разделители-комментарии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще все IDE показывают код сплошным текстом. Или вы имели ввиду навигацию по коду и подсветку синтаксиса?

У меня сейчас есть только Oracle SQL Developer, там есть и подсветка, и навигация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно щелкнуть слева по названию и перемиститься в пакет, тело пакета или к конкретной функции внутри. У процедуры в коде есть синяя стрелка - по ней можно перемещаться от объявления к телу и обратно. Сворачивание/разворачивание кода тоже есть. Переход по `ctrl+click`, автодополнение кода и прочее.

PL/SQL Developer мне лично нравится намного больше (там и функций побольше, и реализованы они получше), но он денег стоит, а работодатели жадничают. Конечно, по сравнению с Intellij IDEA это все динозавры, но работать можно.

Comment: Спасибо. Идея ясна. У меня и навигации нет. А вот по поводу  Intellij IDEA  можно подробней? Она, разве, умеет с ораклом работать? Я думал, что это IDE чисто для языков программирования

Comment: Она умеет немного работать с БД, но я говорил о ее возможностях для работы с Java. Просто космолет по сравнению с тем, что есть в топовых инструментах для оракла.

Comment: Ясно. Так в оракле, действительно так все печально. Я работаю с IB/FB/MySQL - там инструменты на порядок адекватнее. Думал чего не знаю